# Add subview to view at particular position

Tags: android, android-layout, graph

I've used the [this reference](http://android.arnodenhond.com/components/graphview) to display the line graph
By above code, graph gets displayed on separate view. 
I want to display it in particular area of view and not as new view. So, I used this snippet

```
 layout.addView(graphView, 200, 250);
```

This works fine but the issue is how do I specify the starting co-ordinates for this view.
It's getting placed at left top. I want it at some particular position.

THANKS IN ADVANCE !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding view in layout, try using LayoutParams to set attributes of it. I think that way you can set X and Y co-ordinate of view.

Comment: Yeah, thnx. It's working but I'm having prob with `onConfigurationChanged()`. It all works in fine in portrait mode, but when switched to landscape mode, it gives `nullPointerException` as I'm referring to layout of `main.xml` within `layout` folder and not `main.xml` from `laypot-land` folder.

Comment: im not quite sure that i understand your problem...
When i need to save state of app when mode is changing...i use onInstanceSave and onInstaceRestore methods.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state

Take look at this, maybe you'll solve your problem.

Comment: This ex. is only saving some variables like String,int,etc. I want to prevent activity from re-starting?

Comment: im quite sure that u can prevent that. Read about life cycle of activity. On orientation change activity goes in onCreate method and so on. U need to save all of your important data, and re-use it again.